# Laravel Excel::toCollection eats up too much RAM

Tags: php, excel, laravel

I need to write a class that takes data from Excel file, parses it and then uploads it to an online shop. It doesn't matter tho, I have problem with first step - Loading data from excel file in good way. As mentioned above I use Laravel Excel. I have an excel file that is 35mb, 12451 rows, and simple loading it this way:

```
        $filePath = '../public/New_Products_2022-12-23.xlsx';
        $import = Excel::toCollection([], $filePath);
        $memoryUsage = memory_get_peak_usage(true);
        $memoryUsageInMegabytes = round($memoryUsage / 1024 / 1024, 2);
        
        dump($memoryUsageInMegabytes);
        dd($import);
```

returns this:

```
198.0 // app/Http/Controllers/Ignored/TestController.php:28

array:1 [▼ // app/Http/Controllers/Ignored/TestController.php:29
  0 => array:12451 [▶]
]
```

it took whopping 21.97 seconds and 198MB of RAM (which isn't a problem, but if a file with 100000 rows appeared, it would be) to load this file. My question is, is there a way to work on this like Laravel Model::chunk? I stumbled upon Chunk reading in Laravel excel documentation (https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/chunk-reading.html), but it is connected to a UsersImport model in this case, what I can't do, because I need to parse my data before I  can upload it. So I don't want to use any Import, I just wanna get the data in chunks, parse it and return. Is there any way of doing it using Laravel Excel? I'm aware of using yield generator, but that would involve not using Laravel excel, as far as I understand.

I tried to get data from Excel file, parse it and then update it to my shop site throught API.